# Add payment.js to checkout module/page

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript, payment

We are using a checkout module called checkitout by EcomDev and we are using Ogone for the payment module. We have to add a js file to the checkout module. the js file is located at: netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js

What is the best way to do this? We have added this to checkitout.xml

```
<checkout_onestep_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/payment.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onestep_index>
```

But this doensn't add these files to the loaded javascript. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place it in your theme's local.xml file.

You can read about best practice on the use of local.xml here:

http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

You can see if the local.xml is working by following some of the other tips in the article. Otherwise your code should be fine in there as is, with layout tag around it.

EDIT

```
 <layout>
     <checkout_onestep_index>
         <reference name="head">
             <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js</script></action>
             <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/payment.js</script></action>
          </reference>
     </checkout_onestep_index>
  </layout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean with a layout tag?

Comment: Just as per the article, so your local.xml could be:

Comment: Oke, i will follow  the article, and hope it works. Thanks

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: I have that module working myself, the helpdesk are very useful so if you get stuck don't hesitate to call them!

Comment: They say they can't help me any further because i haven't included payment.js into my checkout and its not in their scope. The problem i have is that i see a empty shoppingcart after a payment

Answer (score 0):

When you say that your JS file is in *netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js*, do you mean it is in *[yourmagentoroot]/netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js* ?

There are two method to add JS to the header :

- **AddJs** (the one you use) need a relative path from **[yourmagentoroot]/js**, so your file need to be in *[yourmagentoroot]/js/netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js*

  ```
  <action method="addJs"><script>netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js</script></action>
  ```
- **AddItem** need the type as first param ("skin_js" in our case) and a relative path from **the design root in /skin**, so your file need to be in *[yourmagentoroot]/skin/frontend/yourPackage/yourDesign/netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js*

  ```
  <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js</script></action>
  ```

Magento have predifined folders to include JS, you have to check you are within one of those.

Comment: No the files are in the Folder: [yourmagentoroot]/js/netresearch/ops/osc_payment.js, so with AddJs they should find the files

Comment: Maybe the CSS/JS cache if you have your JS merged

Comment: No i have a hosting company that's specialized in Magentohosting. Where i can flush the cache. I did this before every test.